# Rendering Div in Firefox issue

Tags: css

I want to render something like this in firefox

```
<div style="float:left"> Row1,Column1 </div>
<div>
  Row 1,Column2 
  <div> Content 1 n Row1,Column2 </div>
  <div> Content 2 in Row1,Column2 </div>
</div>
```

In IE it works fine but in firefox what happens is the Row1,column2 doesnt stack one below the other.

[Content2 in Row1,Column2] goes below the content [Row1,Column1].

Can someone help me figure this out.

I dont want to use Tables. Cant use them.

Thanks,
Ben

[Update]this is what I want to achieve i.e after rendering the div's it should look like this.

```
[Row1,Column1] [Content 1 n Row1,Column2]
               [Content 2 in Row1,Column2]
```

In IE it works but in firefox it renders like this

```
[Row1,Column1] [Content 1 n Row1,Column2]
               [Content 2 in Row1,Column2 dsfdsf sdfdsf
```

fsdfdsfdffsf]

This is the issue

I cant copy the css here but this is what it comes down to in the end

Comment: Could you post some html with ytour css please?

Comment: Could you post some code and/or a diagram that shows what you're trying to accomplish and how it breaks in Firefox?  In most cases, the fault is actually with IE, for rendering something non-compliant...

Comment: um.. I'm hoping you know you got that backwards. Please post some css?

Comment: Please use proper formatting. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks Gumbo... I was really struggling with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float your second column left and give it a left margin.

```
<div style="float:left"> Row1,Column1 </div>
<div style="float:left;margin-left:100px;">
  Row 1,Column2
  <div> Content 1 n Row1,Column2 </div>
  <div> Content 1 in Row1,Column2 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

*What you are trying to do is not going to work.*

If you simply can't use a table element, then you're going to need to used fix height and widths for your "cells" or your rows and columns in your web application will never line up.

**[If you want TABULAR data with columns and rows, use tables. That's what they are for](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/tohell/).** (an article from alistapart which should be authoritative to you, do a search on  "Are you saying that HTML tables are dead?")

Comment: I understand that, problem is the guidelines. ITs not in my hand

Comment: What he wants to do will work. From the data he has shown us, it is a simple two column layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="float: left;">Row1, Column1</div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        Row1, Column2
        <div>Content 1 in Row1,Column2</div>
        <div>Content 1 in Row1,Column2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may need to give your inner DIVs in Row1, Column2 a width since they may push the content out, which will cause it to drop under the Row1, Column1.

Answer (score 0):

You could render something like

```
<div style="clear:both"> Row1,Column1 </div>
<div>  Row 1,Column2   
    <div> Content 1 n Row1,Column2 </div>  
    <div> Content 1 in Row1,Column2 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way floats are supposed to work, IE is doing it wrong.  The easiest way to fix it is to wrap all these elements inside of another div, then set the height of the 'floated' element to `100%`.

Edit: fixed http://jsbin.com/upane

```
<div>
  <div style="float:left; height:100%">Row1,Column1 </div>
  <div style="float:left">
    Row 1,Column2 
    <div> Content 1 n Row1,Column2 </div>
    <div> Content 1 in Row1,Column2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is assuming what you want is something like this:

```
|--------|-----------|
|        |-----------|
|        |-----------|
```

Comment: This is what I want but if the text [Content 2 in Row1,Column2 dsfdsf sdfdsfsdf sdfsdfsdfdsf sfdsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfdsf ] is long it wraps and falls below the [Row1,Column1] text.

Answer (score 0):

[The problem and the solution http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7959/whatshappening.png](http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/7959/whatshappening.png)

hence resulting code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="float:left; background: red;">
        Row 1 column 1
    </div>
    <div style="background: blue;margin-left: 200px;">
        <p>Row 1 column 2</p>
        <p>fdsfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfs</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```